# Remove specific td from table with index

Tags: jquery, html-table

I'm looking for an answer but don't find how to solve my problem like I wish.

I want to remove some td from a table. td haven't class or id.

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="ligne-02">
            <th>Blabla</th>
            <td>25,2</td>
            <td>27,6</td>
            <td>22,4</td>
            <td>23,0</td>
            <td>26,3</td>
            <td>28,5</td>
            <td>28,0</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here my jQuery code very simple :

```
jQuery('table tbody tr td').each(function () {
    if (jQuery(this).index() < 3) {
        alert(jQuery(this).text()); // display the good td value
        jQuery(this).remove(); // remove all td
    }
 });
```

I think that if j`Query(this).text` returns the correct value so `jQuery(this)` is the current td in the loop. But `jQuery(this).remove()` remove ALL td and I don't understand why. If somebody can explain to me .. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because when you remove the first item from the table the fourth item will become the 3rd one and so on... so it will remove all the elements

if you want to remove the first 3 elements then try

```
jQuery('table tbody tr td').slice(0, 3).remove()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/aLRxE/)

If you have multiple rows then

```
jQuery('table tbody tr').find('td:lt(3)').remove();
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation ! :) And not needed to use each loop, that's perfect !

Answer (score 4):

Guessing you're trying to remove the first three TD's,

jQuery has  [:gt (greater than)](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) and [:lt (lower than)](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/), and an [:eq (equal to)](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector, that can be useful for selecting elements based on index

```
jQuery('table tbody tr td:lt(3)').remove()
```

Comment: Thanks i don't knowed about :lt selector. But i failed if i try to make a loop for each tr in my table.
If i do this for a three rows table it will delete all td on the first line, selected td by your code on second et nothing on third :

    `jQuery('table tbody tr').each(function () {
        jQuery('td:lt(3)').remove();
    });`

Comment: You don't need a loop, this selects all TD's with an index lower than three inside any TR inside any TBODY inside any TABLE, to be more specific use proper selectors.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
$('tbody tr:last td').slice(1, 3).remove();
$('tbody tr:last td:eq(0)').attr("colspan", 3).css({"text-align":"center"});
```